# Azure DevOps Keeps Creating Default Build Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, devops

I have a YML file that is a standard template that is called by all my build definitions.

Each of the builds passes parameters into the YML file.

Unfortunately, every now and then, Azure DevOps tries to automatically create a build definition called "--REPO NAME-- CI".  I know it's due to the YML template file, but I don't want it to generate that.  How do I prevent this Build definition from getting automatically created.

Comment: If convience, could you please share your yml file here?  Or if you set the triggers as the attachment, will you still have the same situation?https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUW1V.png

Comment: the problem with your suggestion is that i dont even want the CI build to exist at all...it keeps getting autocreated...i guess i could disable it...but it's existence is the problem

Comment: Maybe you can use `trigger: none` to disable the CI when you create the yml file.You can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#triggers. Or you can use classic editor to set your build definition.

Comment: that attribute isnt allowed on templates that are getting called by other templates @FrankWang-MSFT

Comment: @Ctznkane525 what is the name of your template yaml file? If it is azure-pipelines.yml, you can try renaming it.

Comment: you know, it IS called that.  I might just try that.